# How to access old value on intermediate table while updateExistingPivot() in laravel 8

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent-relationship

Let's say [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-a-record-on-the-intermediate-table) . I have an extra column on intermediate table 'noOfUpdates' then how can i access its previous value.

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($roleId, [
    'noOfUpdates' => noOfUpdates + 1,
]);
```

In raw SQL i can to do that. [n_enroll column](https://github.com/kunal254/curiosity/blob/master/coursedetails.php#L32)

sorry for my english :(

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [newPivotQuery](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_newPivotQuery) along with [increment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#increment-and-decrement), `newPivotQuery`
creates a new query builder for the pivot table.

```
$user->roles()->newPivotQuery()->where('user_id',$user->id)
->where('role_id',$roleId)->increment('noOfUpdates');
```

Comment: thanks . but, i just wondering if there is a simple method exit like updateExistingPivot(). I don't wanna chain multiple constraints. also what if I want to do something like [noOfUpdates + 3]. but thanks

Comment: if you want to do something like noOfUpdated +3 you can use ->increment('noOfUpdates',3)

Comment: wow. I should have read the query builer docs completly. thanks again : )